# How to integrate mobile app to real time gps and Geolocation with ionic2

Tags: google-maps, angular, ionic2

in this code map and marker are working well, but marker position is not integrated with real time Geolocation and after marker appears if device replace hundred of meters it is not show moving.

```
initializeMap() {
  var minZoomLevel=16
Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {
this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
{
zoom: minZoomLevel,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude),
mapTypeControl: false,
streetViewControl: false,
disableDefaultUI: true,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
        trafficLayer.setMap(this.map);
        this.Marker();

  });

}

Marker(){ 
   let image = 'assets/img/Untitled-1.png';   
   let marker = new google.maps.Marker({    
    map: this.map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: this.map.getCenter(),
   // draggable: true,
    icon: image
  });
```